# How to span deeper levels in a Highcharts sunburst chart if parent is bigger

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I know that Highcharts can calculate the values on higher levels based on the values of deeper levels in a sunburst (or treemap, etc) chart.

However I want to set specifically the main value myself and it is ok if the sum of deeper level does not match the higher level value.

The other way around works perfectly fine - so having a bigger value on lower level than higher level.

But I want to have it as well if the lower level has a smaller value.

Example data:

```
var data = [{
    'id': '0.0',
    'parent': '',
    'name': 'The World'
}, {
    'id': '1.1',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Level 1'
}, {
    'id': '1.2',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Level 2',
    'value': 20
},
{
    'id': '2.1',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Level 1 - 1',
    'value': 15
},
{
    'id': '2.2',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Level 1 - 2',
    'value': 15
},
{
    'id': '2.3',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Level 2 - 1',
    'value': 14
}];
```

In this sample case I want to span the "Level 2 -1" to the entire size of "Level 2"

I added a JSFiddle for the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/vjsLtppa/

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking as a sunburst like these charts is inherently a hierarchical view (the sum of the children equals the parent for each level). What would be gained by having the child having higher value than parent? But, to answer your question - to force the chart for level 2.1 to fill entire size of "Level 2" you need to set "Level 2-1" value to be the same as "Level 2" value.

Comment: @wergeld I agree with the hierarchical view. however if i get the numbers for different levels from different resources it can make sense that they do not match up, but the percentage distribution inside one level still makes sense in the total scope. I don't want / I can't change the value of 2-1. Then I would need to change the value and make a separate hack in for the tooltip formatter to display the original value. Which gets annoying pretty fast if there ist not only one element in the sub level but multiple ones

Comment: You can add a new property to each node. Call it `displayValue` and use that in the tooltip instead. Still use `value` to dictate the size of the node. You can do this for all nodes so you dont have to pick and choose in the `tooltip.formater`. This seems like the best solution as you have to process this data anyway and you can get what the parentNode-childNode difference would be to add to your childNode.value to get your new value.